# What's different between words "target" and "dest"

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

I was writiing a function just copy some properties from one to another:

```
function copyProperties(one, another){
    //...
}
```

But I confused when I named those two parameters:

```
source and dest
```

or

```
source and target
```

I know this is a little ridiculous, but I still want to help...

Comment: Is your question about the meaning of the words `target` and `dest`, as in the meaning of the actual English words?

Comment: why tag java when this isn't a java program

Comment: The words are pretty much interchangeable, "dest" is short for "destination".

Comment: The word *target* is shorter than *destination*, so it doesn't need to be abbreviated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dest` means `Destination`
`target` is just `Target`

Definition for the word "destination" is (according to google)

> The place to which someone or something is going or being sent.

Definition for "target" is

> An objective or result towards which efforts are directed.

So in my opinion, you should name the paramter for this function `dest`, because you are copying(sending) there those properties.